# How to properly deal with GMT offsets / timezones in meteor with autoform and moment library

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs, meteor-autoform

I'm running into issues working with dates/times with mongo and autoform.

I started with a migration from another DB system, where I had dates stored as strings.

the migration was in PHP and I used the following to convert to Mongo dates:

```
return new MongoDate(strtotime($date));
```

So, for example, I start with 7/30/1960  (july 30, 1960)

And In Mongodb, I see:

```
ISODate("1960-07-30T05:00:00.000+0000"),
```

And, when I view that in my table grid using a helper and the moment library:

```
Template.registerHelper("mdy", function (date) {
  if (date) {
    return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  }
});
```

I get:
07/30/1960

Then, I open that up in a form, using `autoForm` with a schema like this:

```
someDate: {
type: Date,
}
```

and still, I see `07/30/1960`

but then I save that to the database, and look back in the database to see what is saved:

```
ISODate("1960-07-30T00:00:00.000+0000"),
```

(Note it has changed from T05 to T00)

and now when I display that in my table grid I see:

```
07/29/1960
```

But interestingly, if I open that record again in the `autoform`, it shows `07/30/1960`

So there is obviously something going wrong with timezone, or GMT offset, or something like that

Anyone know what I'm missing?

EDIT: funny observation... I logged this question yesterday, Tuesday April 28, and today is Wednesday April 29, yet the question still says "asked today"

[image]

EDIT: adding mongodb tag ... you mongo guys can remove the tag if this is not a mongo issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use moment.utc(date) for formatting the date instead of just moment(date).

So, the helper would be:

```
Template.registerHelper("mdy", function (date) {
  if (date) {
    return moment.utc(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  }
});
```

Thanks to:
http://blog.skylight.io/bringing-sanity-to-javascript-utc-dates-with-moment-js-and-ember-data/
for the push in the right direction!